# Have any of you ever heard anyone pronouncing ayin as "ng"?

Tags: hebrew, torah-reading, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, mesorah-tradition

I have read that historically the letter ayin was pronounced by some Dutch, Portuguese, and Italian Jews as a [velar nasal consonant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal) (ng as in sing). Reference to this can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayin#Phonetic_representation), [here](http://sefarad.revistas.csic.es/index.php/sefarad/article/viewFile/461/559), and [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2164968).  I have also read in other places (that I can't find at this moment) that ayin as a nasal consonant was also used in Poland and other Yiddish speaking areas. This can be seen in the transformation over time of Ya'akov into Yankiv or Yankel.

An example showing this pronunciation in the context of a novel can be found in [*Children of the Ghetto*](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/12680/pg12680.html), chapter 20 when a dying boy is told to say "Shemang" (שׁמע). The speaker in the story is a nineteenth century Jew of Polish origins, living in London.

The usually informative article ["Phonology of Ashkenazic" by Dovid Katz](http://dovidkatz.net/dovid/PDFLinguistics/1993b.pdf#29) says nothing about the nasal pronunciation, just a few paragraphs on page 69 explaining that the ayin and aleph went silent and a quote from Yekusiel of Prague complaining about that in 1395.

The author of [this article](http://sefarad.revistas.csic.es/index.php/sefarad/article/viewFile/461/559#36) states (on page 194) that the nasal ayin could be heard in many cities in Europe until the Holocaust, but he believes that the only place where this historic pronunciation can be heard today is in Amsterdam (page 198).

My question is:  Is this pronunciation used anywhere else?  If it was really as common 100 years ago as these authors claim, I would expect there to be communities in America that preserve it.  I am sure that there would be a tendency for "modernists" to make it silent like in standard Israeli Hebrew, but many orthodox communities preserve older pronunciations out of a desire not to change their mesorah.  Have any of you heard "shemang" or similar pronunciations used in prayer or in Torah reading?  If so, in what community was that in?

Comment: I always assumed that's where "Yankiv" for "Yaakov" came from  - some version of "Yangkiv"

Comment: Where an *'ayin* is pronounced at the syllable coda as a pharyngeal glottal plosive, that could easily be mistaken as a velar nasal consonant, especially by people whose native language lacks a pharyngeal glottal plosive or a voiced pharyngeal fricative. But I didn't think a velar nasal could start a syllable in Hebrew. Do you have any examples of a velar nasal "*ngayin*" beginning a syllable?

Comment: One member of our shul, pronounces "Yaakov" as "Ya'ankov".

Comment: I'm not sure the 'g' is pronounced, more the nasal 'n' like the French do in words like vin.

If it were French transliteration then "Sheman Yisrael". Compare to ne-e-mann. double n to be non-nasal.

Comment: @Fred Good question about beginning a syllable.  I wonder how such a person would pronounce עולם ('olam).  It would be extremely surprising to hear an "n" or "ng" there.

Comment: I can confirm it is still used in Amsterdam and taught in the school there.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, that should be "Yangakov", the ŋ is a consonant and ayin is like chet

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing that leads to S'dom's sister city being rendered "Gemorah" even though there's no *gimel* there?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, I think so, and *G*aza.

Comment: Mike, re your comment to @Fred: See this video, where he quite clearly pronounces עולם "ngaulom" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm12-x_U9EU

Comment: @MonicaCellio @Adám The G from Gaza and Gomorrah are from the Septuagint which reflects polysemy of `ayin (as ʕ and ɣ) in early Second Temple Hebrew.

Comment: i know a few spanish portuguese people who pronounce it this way. And want to preserve it that  way as it's a minhag that goes back a long way

Comment: Twice now I found a relevant article only to see that you already linked to it. Have a video of someone who claims they do this in London https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQKb_3Zqn18

Comment: Plenty of Sephardim I've heard say it like this. I live in the Eastern US.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91253

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that @YeZ is correct. When I lived in Washington Heights (upper Manhattan, NYC), I occasionally attended Cong. Sha'arei Hatikvah, which, I understand, still exists in the same location - across the street from the G.W. Bridge Bus terminal. They were "staunchly" Yekke. All 'ayins were pronounced as you describe, and the Chazan would say "Elokei Yangkowv". (In a way, I think they insisted on anyone who was a Shat"z to specifically pronounce it that way, even if that wasn't his normal speech.)

There was another smaller shul about a block down, on Ft. Washington Ave. between 177 and 178 street. I think it was called *Kehilas Ya'akov* - also Yekke. Of course, the older men from that shul called their shul "Kehillas Yangkowv".

Note that Yekke's also pronounce a cholam as "ow".

I've also heard a few of my Yekke friends sing "Shir Hamangalows" before Bircas Hamawzown!

Incidentally, someone explained to me that this is the origin of the nickname "Yanki" or "Yankel" for someone whose Hebrew name is "Ya'akov". How did the "n" sound get in there?

I can't verify the truth of this claim. But, based on the above idea that an 'ayin was pronounced with the "n" sound, and that Yiddish is a variant of German, this seems like a logical reason.

Comment: This is also the pronunciation for the ayin in the old Spanish Portuguese communities. I actually didn't realise that there were still Jeckes who pronounced their ayiŋ. So thank's for that.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt See amendments to above answer regarding the origin of "Yankel". Perhaps, you can verify / comment / add to this?

Comment: I read in a commentary (I don't know which one) on the _Kuzari_ that explained that the name "Yankel" is a remnant of the gutteral "ע", as it ought to be pronounced. However, the consonant "ŋ" is not a gutteral if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

They are still pretty punctilious about using this pronunciation at Congregation Shearith Israel, the Spanish and Portuguese synagogue on the Upper West Side.

Comment: Yes in Italian transliteration of ע we find also "gn' the prononciation is similar to nnnye. Sepharadic Jewish of Holland also use this prononciation.

Comment: Mazal-tov on your recent wedding, Vincent !

Answer (score 6):

This is **not an answer**. It's a comment that got way too long.

An internet search provided some really awesome examples of this pronunciation used in America in the late 19th and early 20th century (if you're like me and are fascinated by pre-war American Jewish history)

- [A newspaper article](http://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=JS18980610.1.2) in "The Jewish South" dated June 10, 1898, which discusses the nasal pronunciation and the origin of the name "Yankev"
- [A book](http://www.worldcat.org/title/shemang-israel-ten-commandements-jewish-creed-and-festivals-and-fasts/oclc/21123800) published in the year 1855 in New York, entitled "Shemang Israel, Ten Commandements, Jewish creed and festivals and fasts"
- [this charming article](https://books.google.com/books?id=F2opAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA478&lpg=PA478&dq=hebrew%20shemang&source=bl&ots=tau5WH4akn&sig=3Gd8lo7j-XX_5dmww0RVeEElQO0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IHfEVMPKE8zOsQSM74L4CA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=hebrew%20shemang&f=false) from "The American Hebrew", May 1896, on the significance of the "Shemang" prayer
- [A cemetery](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=cr&CRid=2222246) in Martisburg, West Virginia named בית יעקב, which, [when registered as a company on March 16, 1913](http://www.companies-westvirginia.com/the-bash-yankev-cemetery-company-s29/), did so as the "Bash Yankev Cemetery"
- [A prayer](http://www.jewish-history.com/civilwar/prayer.htm) composed by (according to the link) Rev. Max Michelbacher of Congregation Beth Ahabah of Richmond, Virginia for the welfare of the Confederacy and distributed to Jewish Confederate soldiers

FWIW, I've also heard older community members pronounce Hebrew this way.

Answer (score 6):

In proper Dutch-Ashkenazi pronunciation, "ya'akov" would be "Yang'akouv", as not only the ayin is pronounced as an 'ng' sound, but the cholam is pronounced as 'ou'. As a kid I was taught "Mongouz Tzur Yeshung'osi Lecho no'ay leshabei'ach".
We would say Shemang Yisroeil and end 'oren' (davvening) with "Ngoleinu leshabei'ach".

And yes, we would say "leng'oulom wong'ed" (le'olam wa'ed) and Youm Kippur, Roush HaShonoh, Sukkous and Simchas Touro would be in the autumn and Sho'wung'ous would be in the Summer, as would Tisho B'Ow ;-)

I was told that the Kehilo in Frankfurt am Main originally had the more Southern German pronunciation of Hebrew. But when Rabbiner Shimshon Rephuel Hirsch came to Frankfurt he brought with him the pronunciation he himself was taught in Hamburg and was used in Emden and Oldenburg as well: the cholam as a "ou" sound. As far as I know – and I was born/raised in the region Holland and Northern Germany – the 'ng' was typically Dutch and even the Jews in North-Western Germany would not use this. Only the cholam 'ou' we would have in common.

I spoke about it with many rabbis and academics but no one can tell me where it is from.

I myself think it must be old and maybe Ashkenazi Jewry started out with the ayin as a 'ng'. How else would we explain why until today Eastern Europeans say 'Yankele' also with the 'ng' sound?

On the other hand the Dutch sephardim (Portugese) also pronounce the ayin as an 'ng'. But as we know the sephardim took Judaism upon themselves after a long period of being 'in between' x-tianity and Jiddishkeit. So to what extend could they have handed down mesora? I mean until proper Sephardic rabbis took over their guidance.

Does anyone know how for instance Yemenites (Baladi) pronounce the ayin? I am very curious. I was surprised to just recently learn that Baladi Yemenites pronounce Chanuka as Ashkenazim: chanuko.

One more remark: I read somewhere that Sephardi pronunciation would be the Eretz Yisroeil pronunciation and the Ashenazi pronunciation would be the Babylonian. But that wouldn't make much sense since we learn that the nusachos have just the opposite background: Ashkenaz was majorly influenced by Eretz Yisroeil and Sephard by Bavel... So why would it make sense that for as far as pronunciation it would be the other way around? I would love to hear more factual information! Toudo!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Dannie! `Does anyone know how for instance Yemenites (Baladi) pronounce the ayin?..One more remark: I read somewher... So why would it make sense that for as far as pronunciation it would be the other way around? I would love to hear more factual information! Toudo!` Answers should be limited to the answer, while question that arise in the course of answering should be [asked separately](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Consider learning more about the site from this short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Interesting to hear first hand from someone raised with this pronunciation.  Thank you and welcome to the site.

Comment: As support for this answer; the sheet music of famous Dutch Chazzan Hans Bloemendal z"l shows an example of the 'ng' pronunctiation on the first page of shacharit: https://www.nik.nl/chazzanoet/All_Material/Bloemendal-H/HB-CD1/gebed%20-%20traditie%20partituur%20CD%201-sjabbat.pdf

Answer (score 4):

My great uncle when leading the family Seder always said 'Arbang mi'yodeya' etc (as well as 'ki lau no'eh' and bimhighrow yivneh besau b'kaurov').
Our family background is Anglo-Jewish since about 1740 and before that from yekkish/Dutch forebears) and my grandmother's transliteration of the Shema started 'Shemang'.

Comment: Shifra welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Answer (score 1):

Bevis Marks Synagogue in London used what they called Western Sephardic Ayin. That's a 'Ng' not as guttural as the middle eastern Sephardic. I think maybe Amsterdam Sephardic community is the same.