# Is it true that Yerushalmi Briskers pronounce Ayin as a velar nasal when they daven?

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, orthodox

I read a post in a forum that Briskers, apart from following the conventional Yeshivish pronunciation of Hebrew including oy for cholam, pronounce Ayin as a velar nasal. I just want to get this verified if it's right or wrong because I thought that only in the Dutch pronunciation of Hebrew was this found. Also I thought that all haredi misnagdim had the same Yeshivish pronunciation and didn't expect one group to have a variant of the standard Yeshivish pronunciation.

Comment: I don't know about Brisk, but יעקב for example is often pronounced as Yankev in Ashkenazi Hebrew.

Comment: Extremely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53003/have-any-of-you-ever-heard-anyone-pronouncing-ayin-as-ng

Comment: ^ In direct relation to the question I linked above, some Ashkenazim have the mesorah to pronounce the ayin as an "ng". Most likely, the "unique way of saying Krias Shema" is pronouncing it "Shemang Yisro'eil." :)

Comment: Why might you think this is true that you ask if it is? Or are you also planning on asking if it is true that Yerushalmi Briskers pronounce Ayin as a dental plosive etc. when they daven? Please edit your post to clarify

Comment: @ezra yeah I read the post but it didn't say anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

They don't pronounce it as a NG sound alone. They also don't pronounce it similar to Aleph like most people. They  pronounce it as starting like a Ayin but ending with a HALF NG sound. Or at least that is what they are trying to pronounce. They do it that way because  the way some Rishonim  say an Aiyin is supposed to sound.

I don't remember where the N comes in but I do remember that some Rishonim say that Aiyn is supposed to end  like half a Gimmel

Comment: Which rishonim say that?

Comment: I don't remember

Comment: Half ng is sefaradic European pronouncing