# How do the Israeli Ultra-Yeshivish and Briskers pronounce resh and cholam when they daven and during Torah readings?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, pronunciation, brisk

I just want to get confirmation if both groups pronounce resh as a [velar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_fricative), [uvular fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_fricative), or [uvular trill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill). Also if they pronounce cholam as "oi" for all Hebrew words when they daven and during torah readings? I have read of different opinions and vague references but no direct confirmation.

Comment: Rambam Commentary to Mishnah Berachot 2:3 וכל הדברים האלו אי איפשר לכתבם על ספר אלא נלמדים מפי מורה שמלמדים פה על פה

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/is-it-true-that-yerushalmi-briskers-pronounce-ayin-as-a-velar-nasal-when-they-da

Comment: I suppose there's much confusion around, so here's a related question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92139/15256